# Constructing an addition operation to a multiplication so that we get a field structure

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given a "multiplication" acting on real numbers such that \begin{equation} x * y = 2xy - 6x - 6y + 21.\end{equation}

So far I have proven that this is commutative, associative, closed on the set of real numbers, the identity element with respect to it is $\frac{7}{2}$.

I have to construct an "addition" operation so that the multiplication will be distributive with respect to the addition, ie. \begin{equation}x * (y \oplus z) = x * y \oplus x*z.\end{equation}

I've tried $x \oplus y = \frac{x+y}{2}$, but it is not associative. Please help me find an "addition" that is associative.

Comment: Hint: $x * y = g^{-1}(g(x)g(y))$ where $g(x) = 2x-6$.

Comment: Without further restrictions on $\oplus$, something like $a \oplus b = 3$ for all $a,b$ should work.

Comment: $x\oplus y=x+y-3$ also works.

Comment: @user13281 by the title it seems it has to be the operation for an abelian group since we're trying to make a field.

Comment: think I would start by finding a zero element, some $a$ such that we always get $a \ast x = a.$

Comment: Then a multiplicative identity $b,$ that is always $b \ast x = x.$

Comment: That worked. There is an easy bijection, call it $f(x),$ that takes $0$ to the additive identity I called $a,$ also takes $1$ to the multiplicative identity $b.$ Care with $f$ and $f^{-1}$ shows how the addition **must** be defined; after that associativity is obvious, and distributivity confirmation is a short calculation. Very instructive exercise, i would say.

Comment: @user133281, finished it; method in comments above.

Comment: @WillJaggy that is basically what my Hint suggests. Since you give out the complete method, I will post my full answer.

Comment: @achillehui, I noticed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of $*$, let us use $\otimes$ to denote the "multiplication" at hand. 
Let $+, - $ and $\times$ be the ordinary addition, subtraction and multiplication of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $g(x) = 2 \times x - 6$, we have

$$x \otimes y = g^{-1}( g(x) \times g(y) ) = 2 \times x \times y - 6 \times x - 6 \times y + 21$$

If we define
$$x \oplus y = g^{-1}( g(x) + g(y) ) = x + y -3 $$
We will find $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ satisfy following distributive law:

$$\begin{align}
x \otimes ( y \oplus z )
&= g^{-1}( g(x) \times g(g^{-1}( g(y) + g(z) )) )\\
&= g^{-1}( g(x) \times ( g(y) + g(z) ) )\\
&= g^{-1}( (g(x) \times g(y) ) + (g(x) \times g(z) ) )\\
&= g^{-1}( g( x \otimes y) + g( x \otimes z) )\\
&= ( x \otimes y) \oplus ( x \otimes z )
\end{align}
$$
The main point is the function $g$ provides an isomorphism between the algebra
$( R, +, \times )$ and $( R, \oplus, \otimes )$. Other properties of the algebraic structure $( R, \oplus, \otimes )$ can be derived from those of $(R, +, \times )$ by repeat application of $g$ and unwinding with $g^{-1}$. The distributive law above is an example of this general procedure.
Another example is the associativity of our "addition" $\oplus$:

$$\begin{align}
x \oplus ( y \oplus z ) 
&= g^{-1}(g(x) + g(g^{-1}(g(y) + g(z)))\\
&= g^{-1}(g(x) + (g(y) + g(z)))\\
&= g^{-1}((g(x) + g(y)) + g(z))\\
&= g^{-1}(g( x \oplus y ) + g(z) )\\
&= (x \oplus y ) \oplus z
\end{align}$$

**Update**

About the question how to discover $g(x)$.
Given a complicated expression, one strategy to simplify it is repeatly get rid of pieces that look most ugly. In an expression like 
$$z \stackrel{def}{=} x \otimes y = 2xy - 6x - 6y + 21$$
the most ugly pieces are the $-6x$ and $-6y$, so I start by getting rid of them first.
$$\begin{array}{rrl}
& z &=  2xy - 6x - 6y + 21\\
\iff & z &= 2(x-3)(y-3)+3\\
\end{array}\tag{*1}$$
Since I suspect the underlying algebra will be ordinary addition/multiplication, I try to transform the expression to the form $g(z) = g(x)\times g(y)$.
With this as guideline, what need to do is sort of obvious.
$$\begin{array}{rrl}
(*1) \iff & z - 3 &= 2(x-3)(y-3)\\
\iff & 2(z-3) &= (2(x-3))(2(y-3))\\
\iff & 2z - 6 &= (2x - 6)(2y - 6)
\end{array}$$
and the last equality leads to the choice $g(x) = 2x - 6$.

Comment: up to you, i think this is a little deep for this OP; it all can be done at a very concrete level.

Comment: A short observation that saves us from checking umpteen axioms is worth leaving the concrete level.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, a hand in the bush is worth two birds.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I think the specific manipulations of the bijection are what would teach this OP something about bijections, rather than the reverse. Meanwhile, there is just one letter 'g' in my last name, maybe your software is doubling it... Of course, I was hoping the OP would go through the concrete calculations himself. I also hope for world peace.

Comment: @WillJagy sorry about that, it looks like I have a fat finger.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you, I didn't think about isomorphism of algebras, looking at this exercise now, I think it was its true motive.

Comment: @achillehui How did you find find out how $g(x)$ looks like? Did you guess it should be linear and solved an equation for it, or did you have another method, something that doesn't involve guessing at all?

Comment: @user3237992 I updated the answer to describe some meta-principle used to find $g(x)$.

Comment: achille, if you type the at sign followed by the first two or three letters of a name already in the comment stream, it should offer a choice of full names and you can click on one of those. It is also the case that typing in an at sign and the first three letters of a name already present will cause that user to be notified of your comment in the usual manner.

Comment: @achillehui This makes it perfectly clear, thank you.